# Fastest way to reset reflog to current HEAD position?

Tags: git, git-reset

Let's say i'm checking out something in reflog:

`git checkout HEAD@{11}`

And now I want to `git reset` to this position ?
Whats the fastest way of doing this ?

Instead of checking `git reflog` again, looking for the same HEAD number position, and doing `git reset HEAD@{number}`

Comment: "Instead of checking git reflog again, looking for the same HEAD number position" No no. If you `git checkout HEAD@{11}` the checked out commit _is_ HEAD.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to reset your previous branch? When you do `checkout HEAD@{11}` you are no longer on any branch, but in "detached head" state. To recreate your previous branch from your currently checked out commit:

```
git checkout -B your-branch-name
```

(or more explicit, because your currently checked out commit can always be referenced by `HEAD`: `git checkout -B your-branch-name HEAD`)